# PyGObject: Single button, one action for left click, another action for right click?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I have a PyGObject application (Python, GTK+) that performs an action when a button is left clicked.

Right now, that button does nothing when right clicked.

I'd like to make the button perform a different action when right clicked.

Is there a way to do this in PyGObject?

Right now, what I have is:

```
    def setup_gui_objects(self):                                                                                                     
        """Set up GUI objects."""                                                                                                    
        # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop                                                                                         
        self.buttons = {}                                                                                                            
        for button_type in ['Run']:                                                                                                  
            # prints byte strings of hostnames and command names:                                                                    
            # print(self.dict_[b'name'])                                                                                             
            toggle_button = Gtk.ToggleButton(label=to_ascii(self.dict_[b'name']))                                                    
            self.buttons[button_type] = MyButton(toggle_button, self.selected)                                                       
            self.buttons[button_type].set_name(self.color)                                                                           
            self.buttons[button_type].connect('toggled', lambda widget: self.toggle_selected(button_type, widget))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`button_press_event`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.signals.button_press_event) signal and `event.button` to check if left (`1`) or right (`3`) button was pressed.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        button = Gtk.Button()
        button.connect("button_press_event", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget, event):
        if event.button == 1:
            print("Left click")
        elif event.button == 3:
            print("Right click")


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```